# LaravelでmySQLにinsertがしたい

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]表題通りですが、LaravelでDB接続の設定をしたり、UserController.phpというファイルにinsertする為の処理をしましたが、接続まで辿り着けません。今日からディレクトリの構造を学習し始めた素人です。
技術書やネット上にある記事を見て進めてますが難しいです。
お手数おかけしますが、何が足りてないのか、何が間違っているのか
ご回答頂けると幸いです。以下状況です。

環境

```
Laravel Framework 5.6.29
PHP 7.1.16
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:gIFG+pmyN0e3T/YAtyszT6lwne47MS6uHJMLvG4ojFo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=personal
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

database.php

```
<?php
   return [ 
       'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
       'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

       'connections' => [
          'mysql' => [
              'driver' => 'mysql',
              'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
              'port' => env('DB_PORT','3306'),
              'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'personal'),
              'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
              'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
              'charset' => 'utf8',
              'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
              ],
        ],
        'migrations' => 'friend',
        ];
```

UserController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UserController extends Controller
{
  public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $result = DB::insert("insert into friend(id , name, age, sex) value(?,?,?)",[3, '北野武','68','男']);
           print_r($result);
          }
   }
?>
```

app.php

```
'aliases' => [
'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
```

Comment: 添付のキャプチャは HTTP 404 エラーを示しているので、データベース接続の前に Laravel でのルーティングに問題がありそうです。`routes/web.php` はどのようになっていますか？例えばですが `routes/web.php` に `Route::get('/user', 'UserController@show');` との記載があるなら `http://localhost/user` で該当のアクションに到達できるはずです。その上でデータベースとの接続に問題があればその旨エラーが表示されと思います。まずはそちらをご確認ください。https://readouble.com/laravel/5.6/ja/routing.html

Comment: ありがとうございます。routes/web.phpを確認します。

Comment: ログに出力されたエラーのログを全部貼り付けてもらえると、問題を解決しやすいです！